# pydoop vs hadoopy - hadoop python client

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoopy

While searching python client for Hadoop, I found two modules pydoop and hadoopy. It seems both are good enough to work with, but not sure which one has more advantages than the other to install one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most comprehensive documentation of this I think is http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/

Recently, I really think that [mrjob](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) has come out ahead as a clear frontrunner. It has a very active mailing list and it seems to be relatively stable and up to date. It also has nice integration with Amazon EMR.