# How to move a file from local server location to hdfs?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I have a file on my server at location

```
/user/data/abc.csv
```

I need to create a hive table on top of this data in the file. So i need to move this file to hdfs location

```
/user/hive/warehouse/xyz.db
```

How can we do that using python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548097/2308683

Comment: You could use PySpark to read your local file, and write to a Hive table.

Comment: @cricket_007 I want to implement it using pyspark, I plan to create a hive table on top of my file . That's the reason I want to move it from my server location to hdfs location. I can write a shell command -copyFromLocal but I want to do this using python in pyspark. How do I do it?

Comment: Again, see the first link... Big long list of Python libraries to interact with HDFS. However, `saveAsTable` works fine in PySpark, so I ask - what have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Things that I tried                                                                
subprocess.call(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal', '/u/data/abc.csv', 'hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/class.db/abc.csv'], shell=True)
Error :                                                                                                     No alias specified and no default alias found.
1
2nd try:                                                                                                                            shutil.copy('/user/adam/data//abc.csv', 'hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/class.db/class/abc.csv')

Comment: 'shutil` can't access HDFS paths. The first is correct, assuming `hdfs` command is on your OS `PATH`, but again, you've not tried Spark?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am writing this code after initiating my pyspark engine.

Comment: Neither subprocess or shutil use a Spark context... Like I mentioned, you want to use a `saveAsTable` function from Spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to retrieve the file from server. Use this pyhton code to retrieve it to your local machine.

```
import ftplib

path = '/user/data/'
filename = 'abc.csv'

ftp = ftplib.FTP("Server IP") 
ftp.login("UserName", "Password") 
ftp.cwd(path)
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename ,open(filename, 'wb').write) #Download the file from server to local on same path.
ftp.quit()
```

Once the file downloaded to local, then do usual hive query to Load data from local or put data into HDFS then load to hive.

**Load data directly from local to hive:**

```
LOAD DATA local INPATH '/user/data/abc.csv' into table <table name>;
```

**Load data to HDFS:**

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ~/user/data/abc.csv /your/hdfs/path
```

then load it to hive by using hive query.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/your/hdfs/path' into table <table name>;
```

Comment: I dont want to write shell commands, I am within pyspark boundaries. So I need a python code to copy my file.

Answer (score -1):

hadoop fs -put command can be used to put file from local file system to HDFS.

Comment: I think you missed the "using Python" part of the question