# How to access hdfs files direclty in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, hadoop, mrjob

I am working on Hadoop and Spark Framework for clustering of images.
I am using Python as my programming language.For map-reduce framework MRJOB package is used.
The doubt i am having is **how to access the hdfs files directly in python?**
For example if my file on hdfs is /a.txt
now how do i access it in python directly to apply further processing.
I looked at many libraries but i am not getting a concrete answer.I saw snakebite but it is only for python 2.

Comment: Why not reading directly the file using Pyspark? An example: `sc.textFile("hdfs:///your_path_to/a.txt")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548097/2308683